# Match string1 but discard if match string2

Tags: regex

Hi I am trying to create a regex to match a username but ignore if match a specific name, STOPPED in this case.
so I want to match all username excpet STOPPED.

`2013-03-09 04:38:13,311 radius-acct-pl[23279]     INFO: Add 10.2.2.73 to 'By User-Name/alberto'`

`2013-03-09 04:38:50,963 radius-acct-pl[23279]     INFO: Add 10.1.28.38 to 'By User-Name/STOPPED'`

so far I have done `\bUser-Name\b\/([a-zA-Z0-9\\\._]+)`
but this matches STOPPED also

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookahead for that:

```
\bUser-Name\b(?!.*?STOPPED)
```

Here `(?!.*?STOPPED)` is negative lookahead. In other words `\bUser-Name\b` match will succeed only when it is NOT followed by STOPPED.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
(?i)(?<=/)(?!stopped)[a-z]+
```

Gets the username after the `/` unless its `stopped` regardless of case.

Comment: +1 for using the lookahead correctly, but you don't need the lookbehind.  He's already using a capturing group to extract the name, so he doesn't need any help with that.